# Comment dire « reasons behind it » en français ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, formulation-idiomatique

Peut-on dire « la raison derrière cette décision » ou est-ce un calque de l'anglais ?

Peut-être quelques variations ?

Comment: Something we often say is "la raison derrière tout ça". I'm not sure you would use this structure the way you did...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"La raison derrière cette décision" est tout à fait correct et ne sonnera pas comme un calque de l'anglais à l'oreille d'un natif.

Mais il y a d'autres façons de le dire.

Les propositions de **mouviciel** et **at080** sont bonnes :

> La raison **de** cette décision
>   La **justification de** cette décision
>   Cette décision **est motivée par**...  (mention spéciale pour celle-ci)

A celles-ci on peut ajouter :

> La raison **sous-jacente**
>   La raison **cachée** (contextuel)

Si on souhaite modifier la structure de la phrase, on peut également proposer :

> Ce qui nous **a poussé à** prendre cette décision
>   Cette décision a été **rendue nécessaire par** ...

Si le contexte est un peu plus familier :

> Le **pourquoi du comment** de cette décision

Answer (score 3):

Plutôt que:

> La raison derrière cette décision

je dirais:

> La raison **de** cette décision

En variation, je propose:

> La justification de cette décision

Answer (score 3):

Another common construction in French is with the verb "motiver" giving:

Cette décision est motivée par...